# empty result set beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Scraping article from New York Times site and getting an empty result set. My aim is to get the urls and the text of the h3 items. When I run this I get an empty set. Printing the section scrape shows I'm on the right path...
target url - http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&contentCollection&region=TopBar&WT.nav=searchWidget&module=SearchSubmit&pgtype=sectionfront#/san+diego/24hours

```
url = "http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&contentCollection&region=TopBar&WT.nav=searchWidget&module=SearchSubmit&pgtype=sectionfront{data}"
html = urlopen(url.format(data="#"+'/san+diego/24hours'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")
section = soup.find("ol",class_='searchResultsList flush')
items = section.find_all('li', class_="story")
print items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML indeed doesn't contain the data. Looking at the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools, you can see that the search results are fetched by an AJAX query to this URL: http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?q=san%20diego&begin_date=24hoursago&facet=true

Here's a screenshot of finding that:

[image]

You have to open the Developer Tools (try the View menu), choose the Network tab, reload the page, and look around. XHR = XmlHttpRequest which these days is referred to as an AJAX request. It means some Javascript asked the server for data.

This is JSON, so you're actually lucky, because this will be much better than parsing HTML.

Comment: Okay first thanks! Second, I've never experienced that before. Is it possible to parse that for the values mentioned using BS4?

Comment: Parse it using the `json` module which is in the standard library. You'll get a nice Python dictionary which is much better than using BS4.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for a tut on that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about how you found the URL?