# Web Scraping AttributeError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to get a number with a special id on a website. this is my code

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, logging
logging.basicConfig()
html = urlopen("http://example.com")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(str(html), "html.parser")
select = bsObj.findAll(id="myid")
print(select.get_text())
```

But I get the 'AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text''.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

ResultSet is kind of like a list, so you'd need to do `select[0].get_text()` or something.

More here: [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Comment: And it just results in IndexError: List index out of range. How can I debug it now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335219/empty-result-set-beautiful-soup